# PHP - Mask IP Using String Replacement?

Tags: php, replace

Is there a function to hide the last 2-3 digits in an IP so it shows

```
127.0.0.xxx
```

For example?

I know of str_replace, but that can't be used for this, or can it? =P

Comment: [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: And if the last octet is only one digit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$text = preg_replace('/([0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+)\\.[0-9]+/', '\\1.xxx', $text);
```

is the solution I would choose because I'm comfortable with regular expressions and then it shows immediately what it's doing. There are several other possibilities.

Comment: +1 does not modify non-IP strings. Consider setting the `g`lobal flag.

Comment: The asker said "2-3 digits". If the last octet is one digit only, then this doesn't comply with the requirements.

Comment: Global flag? There's no such modifier: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php Fortunately... always confuses me in Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

The preg_replace function lets you replace a regex match. If you already have a valid IP address string in `$ip_addr` and want to hide the last octet,

```
$str = preg_replace('/\d+$/', 'xxx', $ip_addr);
```

If you want to hide the last octet *unless* it's only one digit (you said 2-3 digits),

```
$str = preg_replace('/\d{2,}$/', 'xxx', $id_addr);
```

Comment: ... if the IP is the only contents of `$str`.

Comment: ... but a creative solution, nonetheless